# Copy ArcGIS symbol files to QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to copy the ESRI symbol files for use in QGIS. if not id there a resource to get various svg files to use in QGIS? DIfferent linetypes as well?

Comment: for svg resources, they seem to be arranged in themes, i.e. transport. What theme would you be interested in?

Comment: Although I am a Landscape Architect I do a lot of Planning work. Ideally I am looking for more linetypes in general and symbology related to the natural environment. Transportation is another one that I utilize a lot as well. Really any resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On another note, is there a designated size the svg file shoudl be when creating new symbology of your own?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [QGIS Resource Sharing](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis_resource_sharing/) may be of interest.

For supporting information, please also refer this blog [More icons & symbols for QGIS](https://anitagraser.com/2016/10/23/more-icons-symbols-for-qgis/).